# What alternatives are for Camera.main?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Everywhere I see that using `Camera.main` is a bad practice and that we shouldn't use it. So what is the good practice to get the main camera object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should store a reference to each of your Cameras once in the lifetime of that Camera, and then use that stored reference in the rest of the code. For example:

```
// Reference initialization
public Camera mainCamera;

// Game code, executed once per frame or more
void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = mainCamera.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I only need to drag the camera object from the hierarchy windows into the script component in the mainCamera public variable right?

Answer (score 6):

[`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) is basically kind of the same as using `FindGameObjectsWithTag("MainCamera")` and thus quite expensive.

> The primary Camera in the Scene. Returns `null` if there is no such camera in the Scene. This property uses `FindGameObjectsWithTag` internally and doesn't cache the result. **It is advised to cache the return value of `Camera.main` if it is used multiple times per frame.**

The *DON'T USE IT* actually refers to a usage **every frame**.

There is nothing bad about it if you use it only **once**:

```c#
// Best is always if you can reference things already via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

private void Awake()
{
    // As a FALLBACK get it ONCE e.g. in prefabs where you can't reference
    // the scene camera
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `camera = Camera.main` at the start or awake method of your code and define a variable called "camera" inside the class if you don't want to clutter your inspector